# Converting a Netbeans project to a Maven enabled project

Tags: netbeans, maven

How can I transition a Netbeans generated project into accepting a Maven configuration? There are options to create Maven based projects, but there is nothing (that I've found so far) to add Maven dependencies to existing projects.

Comment: Have you opened the project as a Maven project?

Comment: Netbeans doesn't allow for you to open it as a "Maven typed" project. [well it doesn't give you an option to "open as"]

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You need to create a separate Maven Project. Then, you can copy the code from your other project to the Maven project. This can be done from the Projects windows in NetBeans.

Just select the code files/packages in the tree, right-click for copy, then paste them in the Source Packages of your new Maven project.

Next, open the files which Maven won't compile because they miss dependencies. The yellow bulb on the left of the problematic line will give you options to search for missing dependencies and add them to your project. You need to be online to perform searches.

You can also add maven dependencies manually in your new Maven project by right-clicking the dependencies folder in the Projects windows.

Comment: Thats what I did. It wasn't as bad as I thought. I like the new Maven based build.

Comment: Just a note: If you have hibernate, you'll need to copy the hibernate.cfg.xml and persistence.xml files to the new folder: src/main/resources/META-INF

Comment: what if its connected to git whats the recommendation for branching and keeping track of merged files , instead of creating new master how to handle it please

Comment: Can't it like Eclipse after you create  Dynamic web project then convert it to Maven? I found Netbeans missing this helpful feature lately.

Answer (score 16):

If you are familial with maven, then you can always configure maven even in the later, however it is not recommended.

the only reason behind people(including me ;) ) recommend to create a new maven project, is Maven has it's own directory structure. And that is standard. now if you want to enable maven for your project at a later stage, than you can configure the things in pom.xml, i.e. your source directory, target directory and web app directory(if applicable)

I had a large project in SVN and was disallowed to create a new project. I did not want to support lib management and so I configured maven according to my directory structure.

here's the part of my pom.xml

```
    <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>testpackages</testSourceDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>target/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->
                        <directory>web-root</directory>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Could you explain more please?

Comment: if your directory structure is different from standard maven project, then you have to configure it. Maven implicitely uses several plugins which will expect the standard directory structure. So when you have a different structure, you got to configure those plugins and take control of build process. Example, My web sources are directly inside web-root folder, then I had to configure maven war plugin accordingly.

Comment: It reports `sourceDirectory` as invalid :(

Answer (score 8):

I follow these steps for my desktop Java application (backup your project before doing this):

1. Open your project in Eclipse (by going to new project and browse to your project). Importing the project will not work.
2. Enable maven for this project
3. Add dependency library
4. Close your project
5. Delete `NBProject` folder and `Build.xml` from the project location (otherwise NetBeans will not able to recognize it as maven project).
6. Open this project in NetBeans

Comment: The OP was specific he wanted information regarding the netbeans IDE not eclipes

Comment: He is just temporarily using eclispe to enable maven in the project.

Comment: It works well even if you project tracks a remote repository using Git, once you finished you only need to commit and push. Very helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered by accident, the reason why Netbeans 8.2. opens projects as Netbeans projects instead of Maven projects; after you have deleted the netbeans and ant specific files then replaced them with the correctly formed pom.

Netbeans seems to cache the project types for already opened projects, this can be resolved by deleting said cache.

Windows its located here:

`C:\Users\${username}\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache`

Linux here:

`~/.cache/netbeans/${netbeans_version}/index/`

Mac here:

`~/Library/Caches/NetBeans/${netbeans_version}/`

Answer (score 0):

Improving @JVerstry Answer.. I add **Another solution unexplained here in steps.**

Create a new Maven project in Netbeans. Then copy paste your source code in your maven folder, it can be done in Netbeans IDE Projects View Itself. 
**After this follow these steps.**

1. Add SPRING MVC Dependencies.
2. Add Spring MVC Version to your
   properties section  (Dependent on point 1)
3. Configure dispatcher-servlet.xml and web.xml in your Spring Folder.
4. Rest is to do some matching and configuring your main Controller & JSP / HTML-Page.,
5. check your home page by running.

**Point 1**:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
   <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
   <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

**Point 2**: and add spring.version to your properties section

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.0.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>
```

**Point 3**: Under **WEB-INF folder**, create a file named **dispatcher-servlet.xml**. 
Open the file and copy the following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.youbequityweb.controllers" />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

The  declares support annotation driven mvc such using **@Controller, @Service, @Component.**

The  means to scan classes from this base package to determine all bean classes.

The view resolver specifies the locations of our views(jsp) and the extension.
In your **web.xml**, add the spring configurations inside **web-app** section.

```
<!--Spring Config-->
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>    <listenerclass>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-  class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**Point 4**: This is tricky, now Link your existing main controller to the base package defined in **dispatcher-servlet.xml**. e.g: **HomeController.java** shown below.

```
package com.youbequityweb.controllers;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

@RequestMapping(value="/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String viewHome(){
    return "home";
    }
}
```

**Point 5**: In **NetBeans**, now right click, choose clean and build, get away if any warnings and conflicts and than run your spring mvc application for results.