# How to compile java files using external libraries without using an IDE(Netbeans etc..)?

Tags: ant, compiler-errors

I have a NetBeans java project.

This project (**src** folder) is composed of 6 **.java** files.
The project also uses an external library **library.jar** and variouus **jar** files from apache commons (log,configurations etc..)

All java files (when compiled) are used by an external class.

Netbeans generate a build xml files.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="CityVisit" default="default" basedir=".">
    <description>Builds, tests, and runs the project CityVisit.</description>
    <import file="nbproject/build-impl.xml"/>

</project>
```

It refears to **nbproject/build-impl.xml** but inside of that file there is no reference to **library.jar** neither to other jars.

My problem is that if I try to compile with **javac *.java** it doesn't compiles and just print a long list of errors (probably because it can't find the external libraries).

Most of errors are like:

```
 **can't find symbol <name> **
```

where  is the name of a class/object incluided in one of the externals jar libraries.

How should I do? My goal is to be able to compile my code in another machine WITHOUT using an IDE like Eclipse,Netbeans etc..

As far as I understood the solution is **to make a build file and deploy it using ant** but practically how should I do?

Thank you in advance for any hint.
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preffered way is to use Maven to define your dependencies and build your project. More information is available  @ http://maven.apache.org/

Comment: Thank you. How should I convert my Netbeans java project in a maven project? (Netbeans has a "new Mavel project" but I can't understand what to do)

Comment: Check this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495213/converting-a-netbeans-project-to-a-maven-enabled-project

Comment: I just saw the link. It seems ok (I'll try later). Just a question: when I have a Mavel project what do I have to do to compile the project in an another computer?

Comment: ensure maven is installed on the other computer and then run mvn clean:install

Comment: In this end I solved exporting build file from Eclipse and using it with ant. I accept your answer for your effort.thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Using javac -cp , you can tell the compiler where to look for external jars :

```
javac -cp /lib/123.jar:/lib/abc.jar yourMainClass.java
```

Note how I'm giving the path to the jar, not just the name (unless they're in the same folder as your own code.

Once it's compiled, to run :

```
java -cp .:/lib/123.jar:/lib/abc.jar yourMainClass
```

Comment: but is there not a "general way"? I mean: giving a directory where all jars are. Moreover the resulting .class files are used by other classes and should be run without any additional parameters

Answer (score 0):

Covert your project into Maven project by creating new Java Maven project copy-paste your files into maven source folder then compile.

Answer (score -1):

Please use double quotes (`"`) & semi-colon (`;`) around the list of libraries.

- For more than one libraries separate the libraries with semi-colons:

  ```
  javac -cp "/lib/lib1.jar;/lib/lib2.jar" yourMainClass.java
  ```
- For only one library:

  ```
  javac -cp "/lib/lib1.jar" yourMainClass.java
  ```