# How to build a NetBeans Project in Travis CI?

Tags: java, git, netbeans, junit

According to Travis CI [steps](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/java/) for building a Java Project, created a `.travis.yml` file with the following contents:

```
language: java
jdk:
  - oraclejdk8
  - oraclejdk7
  - openjdk7
  - openjdk6
```

When `git push` is done, Travis automatically starts [building](https://travis-ci.org/wolfram77/java-spine/jobs/57234754) and executes `ant test`. But then it fails because `package org.junit does not exist`.

I do have tests running locally, and *junit* is present in `.\lib\junit_4\junit-4.10`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry,but nothing is present in https://github.com/wolfram77/java-spine/tree/master/lib except a netbeans library definition (nblibraries.properties) ... and this might not be enough for building on "Travis CI". Please upload the junit jars to see immediate results, or consider to shift your project to [Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495213/converting-a-netbeans-project-to-a-maven-enabled-project) or Gradle.

Comment: Thanks @xerx593! That helped. I realized that the `.gitignore` for Java was preventing the *JAR files* to be added to the repository. Now it works.

Comment: Cool, you're welcome/glad to help/happy Eastern! :-)