# Convert Netbeans 8 project to eclipse luna with different server

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, google-app-engine

Earlier, I had created one web project in `Netbeans 8.0` using `Java`, `JSF`, `Primefaces`, `MySql` and `Hibernate Mapping` & I was deploying that application on `GlassFish Server 4.0`. But Now I want convert my same application in ***Eclipse Luna*** with ***Google Api Engine***. and want to implement `Hibernate JPA`.

I tried to import **war file** in eclipse and replace source code but when I do configure *Google API Engine* then server configured successfully but in last getting error message that version doesn't support J2EE web project.

Do you have any basic idea that how to convert Netbeans project to eclipse project with different server and which files need to modification?

I did googling and found some solution but didn't help me.

I do appreciate in advance, Thanks

Comment: Rather convert the Netbeans project to Maven or Gradle, then it will be IDE independent

Comment: I am new to learn and don't know how to create Maven dependency or Gradle.

Comment: This should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495213/converting-a-netbeans-project-to-a-maven-enabled-project

Comment: @rjdkolb, I able to create maven project but i want eclipse structure only instead of IDE independent.

Comment: is there a specific reason ?
Creating an IDE specific project is a little old school and I would not recommend it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99778/discussion-between-piyush-gupta-and-rjdkolb).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After research of two days I found the solution. I just created new dynamic web project so I got the structure and after that I did paste my java classes and web pages in eclipse project. In last I did configure server and modified some property and configuration file.

Now I converted my netbeans project to eclipse successfully and getting output perfectly.

Thanks to stack overflow buddies whose suggest me.